# "403 Forbidden" if I run Magento 2.2.x with FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM)

Tags: magento2, php-7, nginx

Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.1, Nginx 1.16.1, Magento 2.2.6

I have some errors in log-file:

```
2019/12/05 16:58:45 [error] 865#865: *14 directory index of "/var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/" is forbidden, client: ***.**.26.41, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com"    
2019/12/05 16:58:48 [error] 865#865: *14 directory index of "/var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/" is forbidden, client: ***.**.26.41, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com"
```

How can I fix it? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

In your nginx configuration file (nginx.conf) check who is the user. In your nginx.conf the user directive should at the top. Then check if the directory /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/ belong to that user.

Now lets say your user in nginx is www-data and the files in /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/ belongs to root. You should run a command to change the files ownership of your project to www-data instead of root to make sure nginx can access them.

You can do it using chown like this at the root of /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/ :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```